# Cannot send mail to extensions other than .com

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2, sendmail, postfix-mta

I looked around for this one but I just can't find this anywhere.

I have a turnkey Linux server setup on an EC2-Instance on Amazon. It has Sendmail installed and Postfix (Standard installation, I did not install either of these). When I send mail using PHP function `mail()`, and I use a .com email address such as me@gmail.com, it delivers the mail just fine. But when I try something more exotic like user@company.co.uk, @company.net, @company.nl etc. I won't deliver the mail.

According to webmin, postfix is being used.

Does anyone have any experience with this?
Any help would be very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It could have recognized it as SPAM. Check the SPAM directory.

Comment: Hey, thanks allot for your reply. I checked the spam, but unfortuntately, this is not the case :(. I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the domain extension. I ran a query, out of 250 members, only the ones without .com adresses didn't get an email..